# Reverse aggregate data into a possible dataset of observations

Tags: python, dataset, aggregate, auto-generate

Is it possible to generate a binary dataset of observations where the proportions of the resulting dataset correspond to known aggregate information?

For example, I have 3 binary features a, b, c and I know that in total there should be 4 observations where a is present, 5 observations where b is present and 2 observations where c is present.

```
a=4
b=5
c=2
```

I also know that there should be 3 observations where a & b are present, 2 where a & c are present and 2 where b & c are present.

```
a&b=3
a&c=2
b&c=2
```

Finally, I know there should be 6 observations in total.

```
n=6
```

given only this information, for a higher dimensionality case with 100s of features, is it possible to generate a dataset that matches this criteria?

```
    A B C
1   1 1 1
2   1 1 0
3   1 1 1
4   1 0 0
5   0 1 0
6   0 1 0
```